# SELECT COUNT(*) doesn't work in QML

Tags: qt, sqlite, local-storage, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to get the number of records with QML `LocalStorage`, which uses sqlite. Let's take this snippet in account:

```
function f() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(...)

    db.transaction (
        function(tx) {
            var b = tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM t")
            console.log(b.rows.length)
            var  c = tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
        }
        )
}
```

The output is:

> qml: 3 
>   qml: {"rowsAffected":0,"insertId":"","rows":{}}

What am I doing wrong that the `SELECT COUNT(*)` doesn't output anything?

**EDIT:** `rows` only seems empty in the second command. Calling

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(c.rows.item(0)))
```

gives

> qml: {"COUNT(*)":3}

Two questions now:

1. Why is `rows` shown as empty
2. How can I access the property inside `c.rows.item(0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to visit the items, you have to use:

```
b.rows.item(i)
```

Where `i` is the index of the item you want to get (in your first example, `i` belongs to `[0, 1, 2]` for you have 3 items, in the second one it is `0` and you can query it as `c.rows.item(0)`).

The `rows` field appears empty and it is a valid result, for the items are not part of the `rows` field itself (indeed you have to use a method to get them, as far as I know that method could also be a memento that completely enclose the response data) and the `item` method is probably defined as not enumerable (I cannot verify it, I'm on the beach and it's quite difficult to explore the Qt code now :-)). You can safely rely on the `length` parameter to know if there are returned values, thus you can iterate over them to print them out. I did something like that in a project of mine and it works fine.

The properties inside `item(0)` have the same names given for the query. I suggest to rewrite that query as:

```
select count(*) as cnt from t
```

Then, you can get the count as:

```
c.rows.item(0).cnt
```

Comment: Responses added. Do not forget to accept the response if it's right for you, it will help future users during future searches.